# Observables Causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a select box which will be populated using an *ngFor and an async pipe.

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let ccy of availableCCYs$ | async" [value]="ccy.name" [selected]="ccy.name == selectedCCY">{{ccy.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I want the availableCCYs$ observable to be updated based on the values in another Observable Coin$. I have a variable that contains the ccys to use.

```
ccys = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "GBP",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "USD"
    }
  ]
```

I have another Observable which creates a list of coins and while it does this I am setting the availableCCYs$ for the select box

```
this.coinsByCCY$ = this.coins$.pipe(
      map(coin => {
        if (coin.filter(GBPCoin => GBPCoin.ticker.includes('GBP')).length === 0) {
          let ccysNoGBP = this.ccys.filter(ccy => ccy.name == "USD")
          this.availableCCYs$ = of(ccysNoGBP)
          return coin.filter(USDCoin => USDCoin.ticker.includes('USD'))
        } else {
          this.availableCCYs$ = of(this.ccys)
          return coin.filter(GBPCoin =>   GBPCoin.ticker.includes('GBP'))
        }
      }),
    )
```

I am still getting to grips with RxJs and using async pipes, when I run the code I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. If there are no coins with GBP then remove GBP from the options in the select. There are always coins with USD.

How do I reactively set the options in the select box based on whether the CoinsByCCY$ Observable contains GBP or USD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it more reactive then you could extend the `coinsByCCY$` and do something like:

```js
this.coinsByCCY$ = this.coins$.pipe(
      map(coin => {
        if (coin.filter(GBPCoin => GBPCoin.ticker.includes('GBP')).length === 0) {
          return coin.filter(USDCoin => USDCoin.ticker.includes('USD'))
        } else {
          return coin.filter(GBPCoin => GBPCoin.ticker.includes('GBP'))
        }
      }),
    );

this.availableCCYs$ = this.coinsByCCY$.pipe(
     map((coinsByCCY)=> {
       if(coinsByCCY.find((USDCoin)=> USDCoin.ticker.includes('USD'))) { // check if it's USD
         return this.ccys;
       } else {
         return this.ccys.filter(ccy => ccy.name == "USD");
       }
     })
)
```

Otherwise if you do an operation like `this.availableCCYs$ = of(ccysNoGBP)` in your observable, you're creating a side-effect; in that case you should use a `tap` operator.

Comment: Perfect. That works great. And thanks for the tip re tap.